# Pragmatic RESTful API

Tags: php, rest, api, lumen

I am making an api for web app, and mobile app.

The business required that the web app has a reCaptcha, and the mobile shouldn't has a reCaptcha, and should has an extra fields.

I searched for how to make a Pragmatic RESTful API for both web app, and mobile app, but no one said that I should create endpoints to the mobile app, different than the web app.

This is the mobile app design:

[image]

And this is the web app design:

[image]

So, my question is:

**Is this requirements feasible to make? and what is the best practice to achieve this task?**

Best regards

Comment: _"but no one said that I should create endpoints to the mobile app, different than the web app."_ - If the requirements are different in different circumstances, it's better to create specific end points. Just create two different end points which handles the differences and have a service that handles the shared features, like validating the user data, creating the user etc. (that way you don't need to maintain two versions of the same code).

Comment: I would probably add a "confirm password" in the mobile form. Users can mistype on mobiles as well (I would think it's even more common there).